# What is the most effective view and template?

Tags: django, templates, view, model

I have the following model:

```
from django.db import models
import datetime

class Club(models.Model):
    establishment = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.establishment

class Day(models.Model):
    club = models.ForeignKey(Club)
    day = models.DateField('day')
    def __unicode__(self):
        return unicode(self.day)

class Court(models.Model):
    club = models.ForeignKey(Club)
    day = models.ForeignKey(Day)
    court = models.IntegerField(max_length=200)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return unicode(self.court)

class Slot(models.Model):
    club = models.ForeignKey(Club)
    day = models.ForeignKey(Day)
    court = models.ForeignKey(Court)
    slot = models.TimeField('slot')
    reservation = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return unicode(self.slot)
```

In the Slot model, each "slot" can either be "open" or have any other value (usually an email) in the "reservation" field.  What I am trying to do: given a club_id that's passed into a function, display all the fields in "slot" that have a reservation value of "open" and a "day" that is equal to today...and then pass this into the template.

```
def avail_times(request, club_id):
    p = get_object_or_404(Slot,pk=club_id)
    return render_to_response('reserve/templates/avail_times.html', {'times':p})
```

I'm not able to do it with the current view/template I have; it only returns a time.  How do I reference "day" and "club" within the view (given the club_id) and then display the above in the template?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a start, that query doesn't do what you say you want. To get all of today's open slots for a given club, you'd need something like this:

```
open_slots = Slot.objects.filter(club_id=club_id, day__day=datetime.date.today(),
                                 reservation='open')
```

Now in your template you can iterate through `open_slots`, and show the `slot` time (you should choose a better field name here) for each.

By the way, I don't understand the point of the `Day` model, or at least why you've got a FK from Court to Day. Courts are the same whatever day it is, and the only thing that should be related to Day is Slot. Similarly, Day doesn't need a FK to Club (it's still Monday whichever club you're at). In fact you could remove the Day model altogether and just use a DateField directly on Slot.

Answer (score 0):

You should use [select_related()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.select_related) to retrieve the related objects (aka: the foreignKeys)

To reference it in your view, just type:

```
club = p.club
```

This will give you the related club object (with another hit in the db, if you don't use select related)

You already have all those informations stored in the Slot object (p) whose only "real" member is the slot field (as you point out, the datetime field you're seeing)